# Prevent particles from intersecting with a mesh used as a container

Tags: particles

I am new to Blender 3D and am trying to model a garden stone pavement using a particle system.

What I desire to achieve and what I already did are attached below.

[image]

[image]

I need to limit the outer volume of the stones so they stay inside the base mesh. As it is unnatural that some parts of the stones be cut by other bounding meshes.

Comment: What is your question? it looks like you are doing quite well.

Comment: Yes, could you clarify what about your solution doesn't please you? Are you trying to make stones stick inside the mesh limits only?

Answer (score 4):

Particles are probably not gonna cut it alone, I'm afraid. I'd go with a rigid body simulation to make it work.

Add a temporary mesh roughly shaped as the final distribution of the stones, but add it some walls to confine falling stones as below.

[image]

Turn you stones placed above said object into *Rigid Body Active*, and the container as *Rigid Body Passive*.

[image]

Adjust details as necessary, in the end remove or hide the container mesh.

Comment: Thanks mate for the time you are spending to help me. Yes I need to limit outer volume of stones to be inside the base mesh.
As it is unnatural that some parts of stones be cut by other bounding meshes outside the base mesh that I am trying to distribute stones on them.